# I want to time picker drop-down below the page

Tags: javascript, css, angular

[image] I want to time picker drop-down below the page

my code html code is this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s2">
    <input
      ngxDaterangepickerMd
      type="text"
      timePicker="true"
      timePicker24Hour="true"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Choose date"
      [showDropdowns]="true"
      [lockStartDate]="false"
      [customRangeDirection]="false"
      showCancel="true"
      opens="center"
      size="20"
    />
  </div>
```

Comment: which package you are using and also can you share stackblitz link

Comment: Can you use the latest version of ngx-daterangepicker-material?

Comment: i am using 2.1.7 in my project